# Modifying an item in a list of lists, changes also other lists same item position

Tags: python, list

The following code is part of a function but the problem I have is on these lines.

```
# Global variables
NUM_MECS          = 2
MAX_MEC_CAPACITY  = 2
VNF_TYPES         = 2

# Mec capacity to hold a vnf
served_vnfs = list(range(MAX_MEC_CAPACITY+1)) # 0 does not  count as capacity
# All possible mec states as far as holded vnfs
mec_capacity_states = [list(s) for s in itertools.product(served_vnfs, repeat=VNF_TYPES)]
# All possible states with defined number of mecs
mecs_states = [list(p) for p in itertools.product(mec_capacity_states, repeat=NUM_MECS)]
```

and this generates a list of lists as:

```
out: [[[0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 1]], [[0, 0], [0, 2]], [[0, 0], [1, 0]], [[0, 0], [1, 1]], [[0, 0], [1, 2]], [[0, 0], [2, 0]], [[0, 0], [2, 1]], [[0, 0], [2, 2]], [[0, 1], [0, 0]], [[0, 1], [0, 1]], [[0, 1], [0, 2]], [[0, 1], [1, 0]], [[0, 1], [1, 1]], [[0, 1], [1, 2]], [[0, 1], [2, 0]], [[0, 1], [2, 1]], [[0, 1], [2, 2]], [[0, 2], [0, 0]], [[0, 2], [0, 1]], [[0, 2], [0, 2]], [[0, 2], [1, 0]], [[0, 2], [1, 1]], [[0, 2], [1, 2]], [[0, 2], [2, 0]], [[0, 2], [2, 1]], [[0, 2], [2, 2]], [[1, 0], [0, 0]], [[1, 0], [0, 1]], [[1, 0], [0, 2]], [[1, 0], [1, 0]], [[1, 0], [1, 1]], [[1, 0], [1, 2]], [[1, 0], [2, 0]], [[1, 0], [2, 1]], [[1, 0], [2, 2]], [[1, 1], [0, 0]], [[1, 1], [0, 1]], [[1, 1], [0, 2]], [[1, 1], [1, 0]], [[1, 1], [1, 1]], [[1, 1], [1, 2]], [[1, 1], [2, 0]], [[1, 1], [2, 1]], [[1, 1], [2, 2]], [[1, 2], [0, 0]], [[1, 2], [0, 1]], [[1, 2], [0, 2]], [[1, 2], [1, 0]], [[1, 2], [1, 1]], [[1, 2], [1, 2]], [[1, 2], [2, 0]], [[1, 2], [2, 1]], [[1, 2], [2, 2]], [[2, 0], [0, 0]], [[2, 0], [0, 1]], [[2, 0], [0, 2]], [[2, 0], [1, 0]], [[2, 0], [1, 1]], [[2, 0], [1, 2]], [[2, 0], [2, 0]], [[2, 0], [2, 1]], [[2, 0], [2, 2]], [[2, 1], [0, 0]], [[2, 1], [0, 1]], [[2, 1], [0, 2]], [[2, 1], [1, 0]], [[2, 1], [1, 1]], [[2, 1], [1, 2]], [[2, 1], [2, 0]], [[2, 1], [2, 1]], [[2, 1], [2, 2]], [[2, 2], [0, 0]], [[2, 2], [0, 1]], [[2, 2], [0, 2]], [[2, 2], [1, 0]], [[2, 2], [1, 1]], [[2, 2], [1, 2]], [[2, 2], [2, 0]], [[2, 2], [2, 1]], [[2, 2], [2, 2]]]
```

If for example I want to modify only the second value in the second item from the second list:

```
print(mecs_states[1], '-', mecs_states[1][1], '-', mecs_states[1][1][1])

mecs_states[1][1][1] = 'A'
```

Is not only changing the desired value but also other lists values in the same index position.

```
out: [[[0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 'A']], [[0, 0], [0, 2]], [[0, 0], [1, 0]], [[0, 0], [1, 1]], [[0, 0], [1, 2]], [[0, 0], [2, 0]], [[0, 0], [2, 1]], [[0, 0], [2, 2]], [[0, 'A'], [0, 0]], [[0, 'A'], [0, 'A']], [[0, 'A'], [0, 2]], [[0, 'A'], [1, 0]], [[0, 'A'], [1, 1]], [[0, 'A'], [1, 2]], [[0, 'A'], [2, 0]], [[0, 'A'], [2, 1]], [[0, 'A'], [2, 2]], [[0, 2], [0, 0]], [[0, 2], [0, 'A']], [[0, 2], [0, 2]], [[0, 2], [1, 0]], [[0, 2], [1, 1]], [[0, 2], [1, 2]], [[0, 2], [2, 0]], [[0, 2], [2, 1]], [[0, 2], [2, 2]], [[1, 0], [0, 0]], [[1, 0], [0, 'A']], [[1, 0], [0, 2]], [[1, 0], [1, 0]], [[1, 0], [1, 1]], [[1, 0], [1, 2]], [[1, 0], [2, 0]], [[1, 0], [2, 1]], [[1, 0], [2, 2]], [[1, 1], [0, 0]], [[1, 1], [0, 'A']], [[1, 1], [0, 2]], [[1, 1], [1, 0]], [[1, 1], [1, 1]], [[1, 1], [1, 2]], [[1, 1], [2, 0]], [[1, 1], [2, 1]], [[1, 1], [2, 2]], [[1, 2], [0, 0]], [[1, 2], [0, 'A']], [[1, 2], [0, 2]], [[1, 2], [1, 0]], [[1, 2], [1, 1]], [[1, 2], [1, 2]], [[1, 2], [2, 0]], [[1, 2], [2, 1]], [[1, 2], [2, 2]], [[2, 0], [0, 0]], [[2, 0], [0, 'A']], [[2, 0], [0, 2]], [[2, 0], [1, 0]], [[2, 0], [1, 1]], [[2, 0], [1, 2]], [[2, 0], [2, 0]], [[2, 0], [2, 1]], [[2, 0], [2, 2]], [[2, 1], [0, 0]], [[2, 1], [0, 'A']], [[2, 1], [0, 2]], [[2, 1], [1, 0]], [[2, 1], [1, 1]], [[2, 1], [1, 2]], [[2, 1], [2, 0]], [[2, 1], [2, 1]], [[2, 1], [2, 2]], [[2, 2], [0, 0]], [[2, 2], [0, 'A']], [[2, 2], [0, 2]], [[2, 2], [1, 0]], [[2, 2], [1, 1]], [[2, 2], [1, 2]], [[2, 2], [2, 0]], [[2, 2], [2, 1]], [[2, 2], [2, 2]]]
```

What am I missing? I need that each list within a list be independent. I'm guessing that the reason is in the product of itertools but I don't totally understand why.

What would be the solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List changes unexpectedly after assignment. How do I clone or copy it to prevent this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/list-changes-unexpectedly-after-assignment-how-do-i-clone-or-copy-it-to-prevent)

Comment: For a simple example of what is happening you can do this: a = [1, 2, 3]; b = a; b[1] = 'A'; print (b); print (a)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using json to serialize and deserialize.

```
import json

# Mec capacity to hold a vnf
served_vnfs = list(range(MAX_MEC_CAPACITY + 1))  # 0 does not  count as capacity
# All possible mec states as far as holded vnfs
mec_capacity_states = [list(s) for s in itertools.product(served_vnfs, repeat=VNF_TYPES)]
# All possible states with defined number of mecs
mecs_states = [copy.deepcopy(list(p)) for p in 
itertools.product(mec_capacity_states, repeat=NUM_MECS)]
mecs_states = json.loads(json.dumps(list(mecs_states)))

print(mecs_states)
mecs_states[0][0][0] = 'A'
print(mecs_states)
```

output

```
[[[0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 1]], [[0, 0], [0, 2]], [[0, 0], [1, 0]], [[0, 0], [1, 1]], [[0, 0], [1, 2]], [[0, 0], [2, 0]], [[0, 0], [2, 1]], [[0, 0], [2, 2]], [[0, 1], [0, 0]], [[0, 1], [0, 1]], [[0, 1], [0, 2]], [[0, 1], [1, 0]], [[0, 1], [1, 1]], [[0, 1], [1, 2]], [[0, 1], [2, 0]], [[0, 1], [2, 1]], [[0, 1], [2, 2]], [[0, 2], [0, 0]], [[0, 2], [0, 1]], [[0, 2], [0, 2]], [[0, 2], [1, 0]], [[0, 2], [1, 1]], [[0, 2], [1, 2]], [[0, 2], [2, 0]], [[0, 2], [2, 1]], [[0, 2], [2, 2]], [[1, 0], [0, 0]], [[1, 0], [0, 1]], [[1, 0], [0, 2]], [[1, 0], [1, 0]], [[1, 0], [1, 1]], [[1, 0], [1, 2]], [[1, 0], [2, 0]], [[1, 0], [2, 1]], [[1, 0], [2, 2]], [[1, 1], [0, 0]], [[1, 1], [0, 1]], [[1, 1], [0, 2]], [[1, 1], [1, 0]], [[1, 1], [1, 1]], [[1, 1], [1, 2]], [[1, 1], [2, 0]], [[1, 1], [2, 1]], [[1, 1], [2, 2]], [[1, 2], [0, 0]], [[1, 2], [0, 1]], [[1, 2], [0, 2]], [[1, 2], [1, 0]], [[1, 2], [1, 1]], [[1, 2], [1, 2]], [[1, 2], [2, 0]], [[1, 2], [2, 1]], [[1, 2], [2, 2]], [[2, 0], [0, 0]], [[2, 0], [0, 1]], [[2, 0], [0, 2]], [[2, 0], [1, 0]], [[2, 0], [1, 1]], [[2, 0], [1, 2]], [[2, 0], [2, 0]], [[2, 0], [2, 1]], [[2, 0], [2, 2]], [[2, 1], [0, 0]], [[2, 1], [0, 1]], [[2, 1], [0, 2]], [[2, 1], [1, 0]], [[2, 1], [1, 1]], [[2, 1], [1, 2]], [[2, 1], [2, 0]], [[2, 1], [2, 1]], [[2, 1], [2, 2]], [[2, 2], [0, 0]], [[2, 2], [0, 1]], [[2, 2], [0, 2]], [[2, 2], [1, 0]], [[2, 2], [1, 1]], [[2, 2], [1, 2]], [[2, 2], [2, 0]], [[2, 2], [2, 1]], [[2, 2], [2, 2]]]

[[['A', 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 1]], [[0, 0], [0, 2]], [[0, 0], [1, 0]], [[0, 0], [1, 1]], [[0, 0], [1, 2]], [[0, 0], [2, 0]], [[0, 0], [2, 1]], [[0, 0], [2, 2]], [[0, 1], [0, 0]], [[0, 1], [0, 1]], [[0, 1], [0, 2]], [[0, 1], [1, 0]], [[0, 1], [1, 1]], [[0, 1], [1, 2]], [[0, 1], [2, 0]], [[0, 1], [2, 1]], [[0, 1], [2, 2]], [[0, 2], [0, 0]], [[0, 2], [0, 1]], [[0, 2], [0, 2]], [[0, 2], [1, 0]], [[0, 2], [1, 1]], [[0, 2], [1, 2]], [[0, 2], [2, 0]], [[0, 2], [2, 1]], [[0, 2], [2, 2]], [[1, 0], [0, 0]], [[1, 0], [0, 1]], [[1, 0], [0, 2]], [[1, 0], [1, 0]], [[1, 0], [1, 1]], [[1, 0], [1, 2]], [[1, 0], [2, 0]], [[1, 0], [2, 1]], [[1, 0], [2, 2]], [[1, 1], [0, 0]], [[1, 1], [0, 1]], [[1, 1], [0, 2]], [[1, 1], [1, 0]], [[1, 1], [1, 1]], [[1, 1], [1, 2]], [[1, 1], [2, 0]], [[1, 1], [2, 1]], [[1, 1], [2, 2]], [[1, 2], [0, 0]], [[1, 2], [0, 1]], [[1, 2], [0, 2]], [[1, 2], [1, 0]], [[1, 2], [1, 1]], [[1, 2], [1, 2]], [[1, 2], [2, 0]], [[1, 2], [2, 1]], [[1, 2], [2, 2]], [[2, 0], [0, 0]], [[2, 0], [0, 1]], [[2, 0], [0, 2]], [[2, 0], [1, 0]], [[2, 0], [1, 1]], [[2, 0], [1, 2]], [[2, 0], [2, 0]], [[2, 0], [2, 1]], [[2, 0], [2, 2]], [[2, 1], [0, 0]], [[2, 1], [0, 1]], [[2, 1], [0, 2]], [[2, 1], [1, 0]], [[2, 1], [1, 1]], [[2, 1], [1, 2]], [[2, 1], [2, 0]], [[2, 1], [2, 1]], [[2, 1], [2, 2]], [[2, 2], [0, 0]], [[2, 2], [0, 1]], [[2, 2], [0, 2]], [[2, 2], [1, 0]], [[2, 2], [1, 1]], [[2, 2], [1, 2]], [[2, 2], [2, 0]], [[2, 2], [2, 1]], [[2, 2], [2, 2]]]
```

Answer (score 3):

When you build the `mecs_states` list, you’re not creating new internal lists, you’re referencing the *same* lists you created in `mec_capacity_states`. As a smaller example:

```py
import itertools

nums = [1, 2]

pairs = [list(p) for p in itertools.product(nums, repeat=2)]
# pairs = [[1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 1], [2, 2]]
a, b, c, d = pairs  # unpacking 'pairs' for the example later.

nested = [list(p) for p in itertools.product(pairs, repeat=2)]
# nested = [
#     [[1, 1], [1, 1]],
#     [[1, 1], [1, 2]],
#     [[1, 1], [2, 1]],
#     [[1, 1], [2, 2]],
# ...]
```

The thing about the inner elements of `nested` is that they are the *same* lists, by *reference*, as the elements of `pairs`:

```py
nested[0][0] is a
# True
nested[0][1] is a
# True

nested[0][0][0] = 'x'
# a = ['x', 1]
# nested = [
#     [['x', 1], ['x', 1]],
#     [['x', 1], ['x', 2]],
#     [['x', 1], [2, 1]],
#     [['x', 1], [2, 2]],
# ...]
```

So when you modify `nested[0][0][0]`, that is modifying the list that both `nested[0][0]` and `a` point to. Essentially, it’s a slightly more complex version of the problem people run into when they do `[[]] * 10`, and all ten lists are the same list in memory.

You could solve this by waiting until the very end, after you have constructed your collections, to turn the `tuple`s that `itertools.product` gives you into `list`s. However, once you are getting into nested collections more than a couple levels deep, it is time to start thinking about whether a class or some other data structure might be more appropriate to encapsulate the behavior you want.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, I was not aware that itertools.product would just point to the same memory allocation. The truth is that is a great function to obtain all possible combinations between vectors, that's why I used it at first place.

Answer (score 2):

Just "clone" the `mecs_states` list item. See `copy.deepcopy` in the code

```
import itertools
import copy

NUM_MECS = 2
MAX_MEC_CAPACITY = 2
VNF_TYPES = 2

# Mec capacity to hold a vnf
served_vnfs = list(range(MAX_MEC_CAPACITY + 1))  # 0 does not  count as capacity
# All possible mec states as far as holded vnfs
mec_capacity_states = [list(s) for s in itertools.product(served_vnfs, repeat=VNF_TYPES)]
# All possible states with defined number of mecs
mecs_states = [copy.deepcopy(list(p)) for p in itertools.product(mec_capacity_states, repeat=NUM_MECS)]
print(mecs_states)
print(mecs_states[1], '-', mecs_states[1][1], '-', mecs_states[1][1][1])
mecs_states[1][1][1] = 'A'
print(mecs_states)
```

output

```
[[[0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 1]], [[0, 0], [0, 2]], [[0, 0], [1, 0]], [[0, 0], [1, 1]], [[0, 0], [1, 2]], [[0, 0], [2, 0]], [[0, 0], [2, 1]], [[0, 0], [2, 2]], [[0, 1], [0, 0]], [[0, 1], [0, 1]], [[0, 1], [0, 2]], [[0, 1], [1, 0]], [[0, 1], [1, 1]], [[0, 1], [1, 2]], [[0, 1], [2, 0]], [[0, 1], [2, 1]], [[0, 1], [2, 2]], [[0, 2], [0, 0]], [[0, 2], [0, 1]], [[0, 2], [0, 2]], [[0, 2], [1, 0]], [[0, 2], [1, 1]], [[0, 2], [1, 2]], [[0, 2], [2, 0]], [[0, 2], [2, 1]], [[0, 2], [2, 2]], [[1, 0], [0, 0]], [[1, 0], [0, 1]], [[1, 0], [0, 2]], [[1, 0], [1, 0]], [[1, 0], [1, 1]], [[1, 0], [1, 2]], [[1, 0], [2, 0]], [[1, 0], [2, 1]], [[1, 0], [2, 2]], [[1, 1], [0, 0]], [[1, 1], [0, 1]], [[1, 1], [0, 2]], [[1, 1], [1, 0]], [[1, 1], [1, 1]], [[1, 1], [1, 2]], [[1, 1], [2, 0]], [[1, 1], [2, 1]], [[1, 1], [2, 2]], [[1, 2], [0, 0]], [[1, 2], [0, 1]], [[1, 2], [0, 2]], [[1, 2], [1, 0]], [[1, 2], [1, 1]], [[1, 2], [1, 2]], [[1, 2], [2, 0]], [[1, 2], [2, 1]], [[1, 2], [2, 2]], [[2, 0], [0, 0]], [[2, 0], [0, 1]], [[2, 0], [0, 2]], [[2, 0], [1, 0]], [[2, 0], [1, 1]], [[2, 0], [1, 2]], [[2, 0], [2, 0]], [[2, 0], [2, 1]], [[2, 0], [2, 2]], [[2, 1], [0, 0]], [[2, 1], [0, 1]], [[2, 1], [0, 2]], [[2, 1], [1, 0]], [[2, 1], [1, 1]], [[2, 1], [1, 2]], [[2, 1], [2, 0]], [[2, 1], [2, 1]], [[2, 1], [2, 2]], [[2, 2], [0, 0]], [[2, 2], [0, 1]], [[2, 2], [0, 2]], [[2, 2], [1, 0]], [[2, 2], [1, 1]], [[2, 2], [1, 2]], [[2, 2], [2, 0]], [[2, 2], [2, 1]], [[2, 2], [2, 2]]]
[[0, 0], [0, 1]] - [0, 1] - 1
[[[0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 'A']], [[0, 0], [0, 2]], [[0, 0], [1, 0]], [[0, 0], [1, 1]], [[0, 0], [1, 2]], [[0, 0], [2, 0]], [[0, 0], [2, 1]], [[0, 0], [2, 2]], [[0, 1], [0, 0]], [[0, 1], [0, 1]], [[0, 1], [0, 2]], [[0, 1], [1, 0]], [[0, 1], [1, 1]], [[0, 1], [1, 2]], [[0, 1], [2, 0]], [[0, 1], [2, 1]], [[0, 1], [2, 2]], [[0, 2], [0, 0]], [[0, 2], [0, 1]], [[0, 2], [0, 2]], [[0, 2], [1, 0]], [[0, 2], [1, 1]], [[0, 2], [1, 2]], [[0, 2], [2, 0]], [[0, 2], [2, 1]], [[0, 2], [2, 2]], [[1, 0], [0, 0]], [[1, 0], [0, 1]], [[1, 0], [0, 2]], [[1, 0], [1, 0]], [[1, 0], [1, 1]], [[1, 0], [1, 2]], [[1, 0], [2, 0]], [[1, 0], [2, 1]], [[1, 0], [2, 2]], [[1, 1], [0, 0]], [[1, 1], [0, 1]], [[1, 1], [0, 2]], [[1, 1], [1, 0]], [[1, 1], [1, 1]], [[1, 1], [1, 2]], [[1, 1], [2, 0]], [[1, 1], [2, 1]], [[1, 1], [2, 2]], [[1, 2], [0, 0]], [[1, 2], [0, 1]], [[1, 2], [0, 2]], [[1, 2], [1, 0]], [[1, 2], [1, 1]], [[1, 2], [1, 2]], [[1, 2], [2, 0]], [[1, 2], [2, 1]], [[1, 2], [2, 2]], [[2, 0], [0, 0]], [[2, 0], [0, 1]], [[2, 0], [0, 2]], [[2, 0], [1, 0]], [[2, 0], [1, 1]], [[2, 0], [1, 2]], [[2, 0], [2, 0]], [[2, 0], [2, 1]], [[2, 0], [2, 2]], [[2, 1], [0, 0]], [[2, 1], [0, 1]], [[2, 1], [0, 2]], [[2, 1], [1, 0]], [[2, 1], [1, 1]], [[2, 1], [1, 2]], [[2, 1], [2, 0]], [[2, 1], [2, 1]], [[2, 1], [2, 2]], [[2, 2], [0, 0]], [[2, 2], [0, 1]], [[2, 2], [0, 2]], [[2, 2], [1, 0]], [[2, 2], [1, 1]], [[2, 2], [1, 2]], [[2, 2], [2, 0]], [[2, 2], [2, 1]], [[2, 2], [2, 2]]]
```

Comment: Your suggestion is not working properly, if you try to change mecs_states[0][0][0]='A' you'll see that it duplicates de modification